# using uibModal in angularJS v1.48 applcation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use uibModal (from angular-ui-bootstrap v0.12.1) in an angularJS application (v.148).  I am aware of the current angular versions.  When I am trying to use the modal using example code below, I am seeing the error:

```
TypeError: $uibModal.open is not a function
```

I have added the following to the application:

```
angular.module('someApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

In the controller file, I am using the following:

```
angular.module('someAppController')
.controller('someController', ['$scope', '$http', $'location', '$modal', 'someService', 
function($scope, $http, $locaton, $uibModal, someService) {
```

On an event:

```
$uibModal.open({
 templateUrl: 'some.html',
 windowClass: 'modal-danger'
});
```

I have tried replacing $uibModal to $modal (both in the module call and where I am trying to create the modal).  However, I get the same error complaining about $uibModal.open or $modal.open is not a fucntion.  Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?  I cannot find any issues with the versions or other dependencies causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos in your code and are not properly injecting the `$uibModal` provider

change

```
.controller('someController', ['$scope', '$http', $'location', '$modal', 'someService'
```

to

```
.controller('someController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$uibModal', 'someService'
```

also change

```
templateUrk: 'some.html',
```

to

```
templateUrl: 'some.html',
```

Comment: the type was just that - a typo on stackoverflow.  I was able to fix the issue - I am using $moal, not $uibModal (I realize that is recommended depending on the version being used)  Thanks for the input.